# How to create a ForeginKey to an attribute that is not a Primary Key in Django 1.5.2?

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models. I need to make the attribute **c** a reference to attribute **y**.

```
class One
    x = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    y = models.IntegerField(max_length=5)

class Two
    a = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    b = models.ForeignKey(One)
    c = models.ForeignKey(One, related_name='y')
```

The above syntax gives the following error:

CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
Two: Accessor for field 'c' clashes with field 'One.c'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'c'.
Two: Reverse query name for field 'c' clashes with field 'One.c'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'c'.

Comment: I need to ensure that attribute C contains a reference to any instance of attribute Y. I can handle this using validation code too but I was wondering if this could be handled in the Models itself.

Comment: Why do you need that? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Please try `ForeignKey.to_field` like:

```
class One
    x = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    y = models.IntegerField(max_length=5)

class Two
    a = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    b = models.ForeignKey(One)
    c = models.ForeignKey(One, related_name='y', to_field = 'y')
```

and tell me if it helped.
Please tell what you need that for becouse it doesn't look like a good (cannonical) solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason why you should do that. If you have a reference to the Model 'One' you can easily access the attribute 'y'

```
from your_app.models import One, Two

two = Two.objects.get(pk=1)  # To get the first Object, for example
one = two.b                  # You get a Objects of Model One
print one.y                  # Print the attribute 'y' from models One
```

(I hope there is no syntax error inside. Correct me if there are any)

That way you can access the attribute you need. There is no need to reference to a no-primary-key field. In fact I don't think it is even possible to reference to a field which is no primary key. A reference is a 1:1 Relation. And if the field is no primary-key where could be more fields with the same conent:

```
A:  ID_pk   Text     B: ID_pk   text_fk
      1     Foo           1        1
      2     Bar           2       Foo
      3     Foo
```

Maybe this example explains the problematic. Table A stores a Text, identified by the primary_key ID_pk.
Table B references to Table A. In row 1 there is no Problem. The ID we want to reference is 1. So it is row 1 in Table A.
In row 2 we just say 'Foo'. But since Foo in Table A is in row 1 and 3, the database doesn't know which row you want to refernce